# How do I fetch only numbers in grep?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, grep

I have file like this :

```
 other lines . . .    
 blah blah blah (:34)
```

I wish to find the occurrence of numbers in the above file. I came up with:

```
grep [0-9] filename
```

But that is printing the whole:

```
blah blah blah (:34)
```

Rather I want only `34`. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: In the future, also check out the man page for grep (or any other program). The man page details the options required for many common uses of the program. e.g. `man grep`

Comment: You can try this >grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*' testfile

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use **`grep -E`** to access the extended regular expression syntax( Same as **egrep**)

I have created a testfile with below contents:

```
>cat testfile
this is some text
with some random lines

again some text
ok now going for numbers (:32)
ok now going for numbers (:12)
ok now going for numbers (:132)
ok now going for numbers (:1324)
```

Now to grep the numbers alone from the text you can use

```
>grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}' testfile
32
12
132
1324
```

will be output.

Here **"-o"** is used to only output the matching segment of the line, rather than the full contents of the line.

The squiggly brackets (e.g. { and }) indicate the number of instances of the match. {1,4} requires that the previous character or character class must occur at least once, but no more than four times.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice. Also, to match more than 4 or arbitrary number of digits, use
    `grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,}' testfile`

Comment: @FractalSpace when have the constrain of repeating at least one time in `[0-9]{1,}`, the `-o` option might not necessary, since repeating at least one time, by definition remove the empty output?

Comment: It's been a while, so I have no recollection of what I wrote and why :)

Comment: @FractalSpace You can also write `grep -Eo "[0-9]+"`, which is a little more concise.

Comment: Shorter still would be `grep -Po "\d+"` using PCRE.

Answer (score 22):

You can use RE bracket expression `[:digit:]` specified by section 9.3.5 of [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) , in combination with `-o` flag to print only matching "words"

```
$ grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' <<< $'No number in this line\nbut 123 here'                                                     
123
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use Perl style regular expressions as well

```
grep -Po "\\d+" filename
```

**-P** Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).

**-o** Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Comment: deserves way more than 2 upvotes :)

Comment: Note: You may not have `-P` option if running `BSD` grep (e.g. OSX. )

Comment: Why two backslashes? Wouldn't that escape the backslash?

Answer (score 7):

`grep -o` will print only the matching part of the line. Otherwise grep will print any lines with the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**I would use curl to access your file locally or remotely, then I would grep lines with numbers wrapped in (: ) then cut those pieces off and write to file**

the accepted answer ignores there could be numbers in the previous lines of the file, it does work for the example data, but what if the file was remote?

**Local**

```
curl file:///home/$USER/Public/input.txt  | grep -o '(:.*)' | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1 > output.txt
```

In this example `output.txt` in your current folder will be written over, we are accessing `input.txt` from your Public folder.

**Remote**

```
curl https://yoursite.com/Public/input.txt  | grep -o '(:.*)' | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1 > output.txt
```

In this example `output.txt` in your current folder will be written over, we are accessing `input.txt` from `https://yoursite.com/Public/`.

Comment: Why use `curl` when a simple `cat` would do?

Comment: The question doesn't clearly state that the file is local. this answer allows for both.